# How to check if an EditText contains the correct answer or not?

Tags: java, android

I am making a quiz, in which I allow the user to enter the answer in an EditText.
My question is: how can I tell the Computer whether the answer entered is right or not?

Comment: What exctly do you mean by "how can I tell the Computer"?

Comment: either show a dialog or Toast message, I hope you want to show the answer is correct or wrong on the basis of some button click action.

Answer (score 0):

You mean showing an error?

`EditText.setError("Your answere is incorrect")`

Answer (score 0):

Answer in Edit Text form are qualitative data so, generally cannot apply string comparison, but if you have answer to compare sentence to sentence then you can use ==, .equals(), compareTo(), and compare() in java also if you want to use Algorithm and get result then you can use Levenshtein distance with java -

```
public class Main {
    public static int getLevenshteinDistances(String s, String t) {
        if (s == null || t == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Strings must not be null");
        }
        int n = s.length(); // length of s
        int m = t.length(); // length of t

        if (n == 0) {
            return m;
        } else if (m == 0) {
            return n;
        }

        if (n > m) {
            // swap the input strings to consume less memory
            String tmp = s;
            s = t;
            t = tmp;
            n = m;
            m = t.length();
        }

        int p[] = new int[n + 1]; // 'previous' cost array, horizontally
        int d[] = new int[n + 1]; // cost array, horizontally
        int _d[]; // placeholder to assist in swapping p and d

        // indexes into strings s and t
        int i; // iterates through s
        int j; // iterates through t

        char t_j; // jth character of t

        int cost; // cost

        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            p[i] = i;
        }

        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            t_j = t.charAt(j - 1);
            d[0] = j;

            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                cost = s.charAt(i - 1) == t_j ? 0 : 1;
                // minimum of cell to the left+1, to the top+1, diagonally left
                // and up +cost
                d[i] = Math.min(Math.min(d[i - 1] + 1, p[i] + 1), p[i - 1] + cost);
            }

            // copy current distance counts to 'previous row' distance counts
            _d = p;
            p = d;
            d = _d;
        }

        // our last action in the above loop was to switch d and p, so p now
        // actually has the most recent cost counts
        return p[n];
    }

}
```